# Change PiTFT 2.8" screen resolution

Tags: screen, xorg, pitft

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie with a PiTFT 2.8" resistive screen. Everything is working great, except that the resolution is not optimal; icons and text are too big for the screen to be 100% useful.

I tried different things, so far nothing worked.

First thing I tried was to change resolution related parameters in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
framebuffer_width=640
framebuffer_height=480
```

With no effect. I tried another strategy, still playing with `/boot/config.txt`, following what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891235/how-to-change-screen-resolution-of-raspberry-pi):

```
# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
```

With no effect.
I changed strategy again, following some leads on the Xorg side. First, I saw what I could do with `xrandr`:

```
~$ DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --dpi 60
```

That returns an error:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

I read [somewhere else](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=71298) that one could also change it through `startx`:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 sudo startx -- -dpi 30
```

With no effect (X restart, but everything stays the same). I then tried to modify some things in Xorg configuration (following [this lead](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Display_size_and_DPI)), adding to `/etc/X11/xorg/conf.d/99-calibration.conf` the following lines:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "<default monitor>"
        DisplaySize 85 64
        Option "DPI" "60 x 60"
EndSection
```

I got the parameters from `xdpyinfo`.

Reboot. No effect.

I'm out of ideas (so does my favorite search engines). Any hints would be greatly appreciated!